# Why doesn't vim recognize bash self-made functions

Tags: external-command, bash

Say, I defined a command in my `~/.bash_profile`, (MacOS Sierra, Macbook Air, if it's relevant)

```
function sayHello(){
   echo Hello world!
}
```

and while using vim, intend to call

```
:! sayHello
```

It does not recognize, and tells me

```
/bin/bash: sayHello: command not found
shell returned 127
```

The actual situation is that I want compile something, so it would be handy to use external command. If not, then fine, I can open up another terminal, `cd`-ed on the same directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

External commands are not executed in an interactive shell so your `.bash_profile` is not read. To make your custom command available you must turn it into an actual shell script, put it in your `$PATH`, and make it executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Hello world!"
```

But there's a much better way to "compile something": `:help :make`.