# Call custom bash function from Vim

Tags: vimscript, command-line, external-command, bash

I have created a bash function, in its own `.sh` file, which I want to use from within Vim, and later use if from within the lightline config file. I have tried many ways, but I cannot make it work.

Specifically, I have tried with the `!source` command, but it doesn't work. Since I'm using a macOS, I have added the sourcing of the function script in the proper place in the `/etc/bashrc` file, so the sourcing will happen in a non-interactive shell.

Still nothing.

My command is called `myTest` and it is:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function myTest{
    echo "OK"
}
```

and is at the `test_function.sh` file.

Since I have read the relevant question of [Why doesn't vim recognize bash self-made functions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10404/why-doesnt-vim-recognize-bash-self-made-functions), I have copied the `test_function.sh` to `/etc/` and I have at my `/etc/bashrc`

```bash
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
    source /etc/test_function.sh
    return
fi
```

This is why in MacOS, the non-interactive shells read the `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/profile` files.

Also I have added the sourcing of the `test_function.sh` file in the `/etc/profile` file, having:

```bash
if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
else
    source /etc/test_function.sh
fi
```

When I'm trying to do in Vim `:!myTest` I'm always getting `Command not found`.

Any help?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the questions. I believe the shell executed by vim is not an interactive shell, so it won't read `bashrc` files. You can change this by adding `/ic` to `shellcmdflag` option

Comment: In MacOS, the non-interactive shells run the `/etc/basrhc` or `/etc/profile/`. That is why I'm mentioning this.

Comment: Why not create a script instead and place it somewhere in your PATH? Then calling it from any shell and from tools like Vim should just work

Comment: Are you sure? That's against the documented behaviour for at least bash. In any case, I would use `:set verbose=5` then run a custom command like `:!true` and observe the shell command that is being issued. From there you can further debug on how to source your functions (or add parameters to the 'shellcmdflag' and other related options